# unhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in node JS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I am following along with this MERN tutorial on Youtube.

This is the Github link with all folders and code.

https://github.com/bradtraversy/mern_shopping_list

So far, the connection to the database is established, I can do GET requests with Postman, but i get the following error message when I try to send a POST request.

unhandledPromiseRejectionWarning -- item validation failed: name:path name is required.

The relevant code is, server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const items = require('./routes/api/items');

const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB Config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

// Connect to Mongo
mongoose
.connect(db, {useNewUrlParser: true}) // Adding new mongo url parser
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

// Use Routes
app.use('/api/items', items);

// Serve static assets if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
// Set static folder
app.use(express.static('client/build'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
}



const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

And this is the code for the routes, /routes/api/items

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

 // Item Model
 const Item = require('../../models/Item');

// @route   GET api/items
// @desc    Get All Items
// @access  Public
 router.get('/', (req, res) => {
 Item.find()
 .sort({ date: -1 })
 .then(items => res.json(items));
  });

 // @route   POST api/items
 // @desc    Create An Item
 // @access  Public
 router.post('/', (req, res) => {
 const newItem = new Item({
 name: req.body.name
 });

 newItem.save().then(item => res.json(item));
 });

 // @route   DELETE api/items/:id
 // @desc    Delete A Item
 // @access  Public
 router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
 Item.findById(req.params.id)
 .then(item => item.remove().then(() => res.json({ success: true })))
 .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

What is going on here it seems that this part has the error:

```
 router.post('/', (req, res) => {
 const newItem = new Item({
 name: req.body.name
 });
```

Or the path/routing. Am at the end of my wits.

I am adding the Item.js code here:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
name: {
type: String,
required: true
},
date: {
type: Date,
default: Date.now
}
 });

module.exports = Item = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);
```

Comment: can you post the code of item model?

Comment: @Sandeep, the item model code is in the question, second half of the text. Those are the full files.
Or just this:
https://github.com/bradtraversy/mern_shopping_list/blob/master/models/Item.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a mongoose error validating the item model, it seems either req.body.name is null / undefined or your bodyparser is not setup correctly for your use case.

It depends how you handle your request with postman or your bodyparser setup, check the bodyparser documentation in your case it should only parse json bodies, not urls.

Check your postman uses form-data instead of url-encoded body and your request includes a Content-Type header of value application/json.

Alternatively you could accept both json and url-encoded by adding

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({"extended":true}))
```

Comment: I have tried that and made sure the JSON is valid, but I still get an error message, this time it looks slightly different.
message: "path name is required", value "undefined", item validation failed

Comment: It took a bot more than that but I got it resolved, thank you.